# Magento2 Limit product collection for a specfic category

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm trying to show newly added 30 products on the category list page for a specific category. it has more than 1k products.
I have tried to **modify temporarily the code** in the following file but it never works:

**Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;**

Original code:

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
            $this->_productCollection = $this->initializeProductCollection();
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
```

Updated code:

```
 protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
            $this->_productCollection = $this->initializeProductCollection();
        }

        return $this->_productCollection->setPageSize(30);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not update core files of magento. This is not a good practice.

I would suggest creating a new class, ideally in your Model folder which would do this for you.

can you try this code to see that only 30 records are returned?

```
$this->_productCollection->setCurPage(1);
$this->_productCollection->setPageSize(30);
return $this->_productCollection;
```

Comment: Did you read the post carefully? I am doing this temporarily, If the code will work then will create a plugin